# Проблемы с фильтром в CollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

С этим `CollectionView` происходят чудеса. Создал я его на основе какой то коллекции. Добавил фильтр по одному из свойств элементов. При добавлении элементов в основную коллекцию, `CollectionView` это подхватывает, однако при изменении свойства, по которому стоит фильтр, происходит странная фигня. `CollectionView.Count` остается неизменным, однако представление результатов меняется. На MSDN нет подробного описания как работает этот класс. Гуглил и тоже не нашел ничего. Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: А вы live shaping включили? http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/10/05/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-10-live-shaping/

Comment: @VladD, к сожалению не помогло :(  Хотя я еще посмотрю, может это мой косяк... но завтра